# Umbraco (Jquery is Possibility) - How to make two <ul> "related" when they are ordered

Tags: jquery, umbraco

Interesting Dilemma - Basically I have an Umbraco template + macro setup where I am creating two lists from the properties of a document type.

So for example:
Property 1: Name
Property 2: Unit

**What I am attempting to do:** 
Use two buttons. One that is order by name and the other that is order by Unit to allow users to order alphabetically A-Z by name, and Numerically 0-9 by Unit

**The Problem:** 
When sorting either of these lists via the .orderby function within Umbraco, It will order the one list but not re-arrange the other to suit.

So my question is, How do I make these Unordered lists "Related" when a sort is performed?

**EDIT: Code to display the records.**

```
@inherits umbraco.MacroEngines.DynamicNodeContext

<div>
    <p>Filter By Name Button</p> <!-- Created as a div to target it with Jquery Perhaps? -->
</div>
<div>
    <p>Filter By Unit Button</p> <!-- Created as a div to target it with Jquery Perhaps? -->
</div>

<ul>
     @foreach (var page in Model.Children.Where("Visible"))
    { 
    <li><a href="@page.Url">@page.firstName @page.surname</a></li>
    }
</ul>

<ul>
    @foreach (var child in Model.Children.Where("Visible"))
    {
        <li><a href="@child.Url">@child.unitNumber</a></li> 
    }
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you include the relevant code, so we can se what you've done so far?  Why is the data in 2 different lists instead of a table if the data is always tied together? To me it almost sounds like you should be using javascript to sort the data client-side.

Comment: @Scherling Will add relevant code to bottom of post. The reason it is done in two lists is for interests sake to understand if it would be possible without using a table. And yes I believe using Javascript/Jquery would probably be the best approach.

Comment: Try declaring a variable called 'children' var children = Model.Children.Where("visible") outside the for statements, and then iterate over that in both 'for' statements: foreach(var child in children).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be to write the unordered lists as separate macros, to which you pass a sorting parameter that is used to generate the required foreach/orderby loops.

Fundamentally....

```
<div>
    <p>Filter By Name Button</p> 
    <!-- use you preferred approach to set nameSortOption -->
</div>
<div>
    <p>Filter By Unit Button</p>
    <!-- use you preferred approach to set unitSortOption -->
</div>


@RenderPage("~/macroScripts/nameList.cshtml", nameSortOption);
@RenderPage("~/macroScripts/unitList.cshtml", unitSortOption);
```